# Oracle with Spring roo

Tags: java, oracle, spring, spring-roo

I've been try to get spring roo generating entities from an oracle database.

However I kept getting the error JDBC driver not available for `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`

I've installed my `ojdbc14.jar` to my local maven respository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

I've check my pom.xml and it points to the correct version and when I mvn clean install it compiles correctly.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've had it work using MySql but no job with Oracle.

What am I doing wrong ?

`Roo version 1.2.2.RELEASE`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2</version>
    <classifier />
</dependency>
```

....

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2</version>
</dependency>



#Updated at Tue Nov 13 22:43:01 NZDT 2012
#Tue Nov 13 22:43:01 NZDT 2012
database.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@[server.ip]\:1521\:orcl
database.username=MYUSER
database.password=MYPASSWORD
```

Where [server.ip] is the databases ip address

Hi,

I didn't do anything with OSGI.

After downloading the jar you mentioned. (Downloaded it from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/DownloadbizaQutebndjar.htm)

I ran the command you gave me but it produced an error.

oracle/sql/converter_xcharset
  lx20001.glb
  lx20002.glb
  lx2001f.glb
  lx200b2.glb

One error
1 : Unresolved references to [javax.naming, javax.naming.directory, javax.naming.spi, javax.net, javax.net.ssl, javax.resource, javax.resource.spi, javax.resource.spi.endpoint, javax.resource.spi.security, javax.security.auth, javax.security.cert, javax.sql, javax.sql.rowset, javax.sql.rowset.spi, javax.transaction.xa, javax.xml.parsers, oracle.i18n.text.converter, oracle.ons, oracle.security.pki, org.w3c.dom, org.xml.sax, org.xml.sax.helpers] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:ojdbc14.jar]: [oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCacheManager$1.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleCachedRowSetReader.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleRuntimeLoadBalancingEventHandlerThread$1.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSet.class, oracle/jdbc/internal/OracleConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleManagedConnectionMetaData.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXAConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXAException.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXADataSource.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleOCIConnectionPool.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleConnectionManager.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleJDBCRowSet.class, oracle/net/nt/TcpsConfigure.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OraclePredicate.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleRuntimeLoadBalancingEventHandlerThread.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleResourceAdapter.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCacheTimeOutThread.class, oracle/net/jndi/CustomSSLSocketFactory.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleRowSetMetaData.class, oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CXAResource.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleFilteredRowSet.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXid.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSetXmlWriter.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleJoinable.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCacheImpl.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleManagedConnectionFactory.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleFailoverEventHandlerThread$1.class, oracle/sql/converter/CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionEventListener.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSetXmlReaderImpl.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleXAConnectionCacheImpl.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSetXmlWriterImpl.class, oracle/jdbc/driver/PhysicalConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXADataSource.class, oracle/net/jndi/TrustManagerSSLSocketFactory.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXAResource.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXAResource.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCacheEventListener.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleRowSetListenerAdapter.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSetXmlReaderDomHandler.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleConnectionRequestInfo.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSourceFactory.class, oracle/net/jndi/JndiAttrs.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleJoinRowSet.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSetXmlReader.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXAHeteroConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CXAConnection.class, oracle/net/nt/CustomSSLSocketFactory.class, oracle/net/nt/TcpsNTAdapter.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleCachedRowSetWriter.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleCachedRowSet.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OraclePooledConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleFailoverEventHandlerThread.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXAConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.class, oracle/jdbc/driver/LogicalConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCacheManager.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleRowSet.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleImplicitConnectionCache.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleManagedConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCache.class, oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXAHeteroResource.class, oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class, oracle/jdbc/rowset/OracleWebRowSetXmlReaderContHandler.class, oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleLocalTransaction.class, oracle/net/jndi/TrustManager.class, oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.class]

So I didn't get the expected result.

Any idea on this ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you post the section in your `pom.xml` which includes this as a dependency? =)

Comment: <pre class="prettyprint"><dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <version>10.2.0.2</version>
  <classifier />
</dependency></pre>

Comment: sorry about formatting can't get it working

Comment: try to define the appropriate scope of the depedancy.

Comment: what should I define it as ? I set it as compile and I still got the same result

Comment: Could you try changing it to `runtime`? =)

Comment: I think the POM is not the problem. I would guess that the oracle jar is not correct deployed. Do you use a Server? Which one? Do you configure your Database connection via JNDI?

Comment: I configure my database connection in the database.properties file. I have the correct detail there, i've added my connection details. I want to use a server but I just want to be able to reverse engineer the database first using spring roo

Answer (score 1):

Did you create an Oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc) for OSGI? From [Roo docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html):

> currently there are no open-source JDBC drivers for Oracle or DB2 and
>   Roo does not provide OSGi drivers for these databases.

You can follow instructions in the given docs. Otherwise, the biz.aQute.bnd.jar helps you to create an OSGi bundle version of the OJDBC driver.

To do that download [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/biz/biz.aQute.bnd-latest.jar.zip) zip file and unzip it. Then in the same folder put your ojdbc14.jar and run the command:

```
   java -jar biz.aQute.bnd.jar wrap ojdbc14.jar
```

I get one warning (Superfluous export-package instructions: [oracle.net, oracle, oracle.jpub, oracle.security, oracle.core]) which I ignore.

As a result of this step you should get a new file: ojdbc14.bar

Rename it whatever you want but with .jar extension. e.g. 'ojdbc14-osgi.jar'

Install the jar in roo with

```
roo> osgi start --url file:///tmp/ojdbc14-osgi.jar
roo> database reverse engineer ... and so on
```

Just one thing to note. Remember to edit the version of the ojdbc14 artifactId in the Roo generated pom.xml if necessary.

Hope it helps. I have done it with 3 projects and 3 databases without problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error during running with `mvn jetty:run`, or `mvn tomcat:run` you can try adding the dependency to the tomcat and jetty config:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
    <httpsPort>9443</httpsPort>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
             <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
             <version>10.2.0.2</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
        <configuration>
            <webAppConfig>
                <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
            </webAppConfig>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
             <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
             <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
             <version>10.2.0.2</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the problem during running at all. I want to be able to call "database introspect ..." and "database reverse ..." so i can reverse engineer the database, but spring roo is throwing the exception. So its outside domain of jetty or tomcat